# How to add all integer from String in sequence?

Tags: java

for Example:

2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26

but i does not get desired results

when i add all char it gives 
output as:
266

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectEu {
  public static void main(String...rDX) {
    int degree = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    String store = Integer.toString((int)Math.pow(2,degree));
    char [] finals  = store.toCharArray();

    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = store.length(); i < n; i++) {
        System.out.printf("values[%d] --> %c \n",i, finals[i]);
        temp = temp + finals[i];
    }

    System.out.println(temp);
 }
}
```

Comment: Pratik did my answer help you?

Comment: Pratik Katariya, if my answer helped you can you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting this error is because `temp` is an integer, but `finals[i]` is a character, so it converts the characters into ASCII values and adds them. You can fix this problem by doing:

```
for (int i = 0, n = store.length(); i < n; i++) {
    char ch = store.charAt(i);
    int digit = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(ch));
    temp = temp + digits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
temp = temp + finals[i];
```

sums `temp` and the **ASCII code** of the char stored in `finals[i]`.
You can get the value of the digit by this:

```
temp = temp + finals[i] - '0';
```

This means that by subtracting from the digit's ASCII code the ASCII code of `0` you get the number value of the digit.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding a character to an integer, you are adding the integer **code** of the character, not its actual numeric value .

What you need is [`Character.getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) :

```
temp = temp + Character.getNumericValue(finals[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int sum = store.chars()
               .boxed()
               .map(Character::getNumericValue)
               .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
               .sum();
```